# How do i remove ugly table cell borders?

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

I'm trying to remove ugly blue table cell borders and have been unable to so via HTML, inline CSS, and internal CSS.  I am green - hence the poorly written code.

Here is some code from the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: none;


}

</style>
```

Here is some code from the body:

```
<body>
  <button class="collapsible">Neutral</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p> </p>
    <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="15" border="none">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <a href="/images/MV-B-BLK1_full.jpg">
            <img src="/images/MV-B-BLK1.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to     view" border="20" hspace="20" /></a>
          <br />
          Onyx MV-B-BLK1
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <a href="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
            <img src="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx-t.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to     view" border="20"
              hspace="20" /></a>
          <br />
          Steel Blue
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <a href="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
            <img src="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx-t.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to     view" border="20"
              hspace="20" /></a>

          <br />
          Peach
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <a href="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
            <img src="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx-t.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to     view" border="20"
              hspace="20" /></a>
          <br />

          Aqua
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <a href="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
            <img src="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx-t.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to     view" border="20"
              hspace="20" /></a>
          <br />
          Blue
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <a href="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
            <img src="/images/xxxxxxxxxxx-t.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to  view" border="20" hspace="20" /></a>
          <br />
          Plum
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Blue</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Brown</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Green</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

I would love to remove these ugly blue borders so there is no border at all around the images/cells.

Comment: Just curious, why did you choose a table layout instead of a div layout? Is this for a standard HTML document or does it have to be a table because of compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `table borders` at all.  Those borders were created by the `border="20"` attributes you have hardcoded into your img tags.

```
<img src="/images/MV-B-BLK1.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Click to     view" border="20" hspace="20" /></a>
```

Change or remove the `border="20"` and see what happens.

The reason the color is blue, is that it is the default unstyled color for an anchor tag, which you get because all the images are children of anchor tags.

In the future, please familiarize yourself with the chrome devtools.  A quick inspection of these elements would show you what you are looking at for any individual element on the page, and what styles are applied to it.

Answer (score 4):

Take out that `border="20"`, should sort it.